# Установка linux на mac

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac

Записал флешку в дмг запустился с нее, минуту загружалась ubuntu и выдала это, помогите кто знает, что делать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может эта статья чем поможет  [Убунту с яблочным вкусом: Ubuntu на Apple iMac](http://habrahabr.ru/post/100514/)

Comment: А виртуальной машины не будет достаточно? [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), например.

Comment: А на обычном pc запускается?

Answer (score 2):

При запуске Ubuntu с диска имеются дополнительные параметры, вызываются при нажатии клавиши F6. Среди параметров имеются `noapic/nolapic/acpi=off`. 
Попробуйте использовать эти параметры, должно помочь.

Comment: Там второй раз точно буква "l" есть в  "nolapic"?

Comment: По памяти писал, вообще acpi=off точно есть и должно помочь.